# How to grant execute access to a specific set of command to one group, and another set to another group

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, permissions

Say there is a set of shell commands {ls, cat, kill}

I want to enable users in group A to be able to execute the commands {ls, cat}
And users in group B to be able to execute the commands {cat, kill}

How to do that, what are the best approaches ?

I thought about some solutions, but they don't seem 100% secured.

Comment: There are commercial applications for this sort of thing, Centrify comes to mind.

Comment: A problem in the example: usually `kill` is  a _shell builtin command_ (check it with `type kill`). If you enable users to have a `shell` I'm afraid you will not find a way to avoid them the use of `kill` (unless you modify the source code of the `shell` in a proper way and you recompile it...). Different is instead if you want to pre-empt the use of `/bin/kill`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the way to restrict the possibility to execute commands is the [restricted shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Restricted-Shell.html).
Excerpt from the manual, where is said that the following are disallowed or not performed:

```
Changing directories with the cd builtin.
Setting or unsetting the values of the SHELL, PATH, ENV, or BASH_ENV variables.
Specifying command names containing slashes.
Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the . builtin command.
Specifying a filename containing a slash as an argument to the -p option to the hash builtin command.
Importing function definitions from the shell environment at startup.
Parsing the value of SHELLOPTS from the shell environment at startup.
Redirecting output using the ‘>’, ‘>|’, ‘<>’, ‘>&’, ‘&>’, and ‘>>’ redirection operators.
Using the exec builtin to replace the shell with another command.
Adding or deleting builtin commands with the -f and -d options to the enable builtin.
Using the enable builtin command to enable disabled shell builtins.
Specifying the -p option to the command builtin.
Turning off restricted mode with ‘set +r’ or ‘set +o restricted’.
```

After that you can add link to the command you desire they can execute.

---

Maybe another path to your goal should be through **the use of `sudo`**.
In your case you can edit `sudoers` file (with `visudo`) and obtain something similar to:

```
User_Alias     USERS_GROUP_A = joe, mike, cedric
User_Alias     USERS_GROUP_B = jude, zoe, cedric
Cmnd_Alias     COMMANDS_GROUP_A = /bin/ls,    /bin/cat, /usr/bin/zip
Cmnd_Alias     COMMANDS_GROUP_B = /bin/kill,  /bin/cat, /usr/bin/zip

USERS_GROUP_A ALL= COMMANDS_GROUP_A
USERS_GROUP_B ALL= COMMANDS_GROUP_B
# users of the group USERS_GROUP_A may run /bin/ls, /bin/cat, and /usr/bin/zip 
# from any machine (ALL).
# users of the group USERS_GROUP_B may run /bin/kill,/bin/cat and /usr/bin/zip
# from any machine (ALL).
```

Notes:

- A problem in the example: usually `kill` is a *shell builtin command* (check it with `type kill`). If you enable users to have a `shell` I'm afraid you will not find a way to avoid them the use of `kill` (unless you modify the source code of the shell in a proper way and you recompile it...).
- If the commands that you want to close for those users are with `read` and `execution` attribute set for all (e.g. `ls -l /usr/bin/zip`)

  ```
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      188296 Oct 21  2013 /usr/bin/zip
  ```

  maybe you can use a workaround, restricting the `execution` attribute to only owner and his group `sudo chattr o-x /usr/bin/zip`,

  ```
    -rwxr-xr-- 1 root root      188296 Oct 21  2013 /usr/bin/zip
  ```

  adding a new user (e.g. *cooluser*) to that group (maybe with `/usr/sbin/nologin` as `shell`), and writing the following 2 lines instead the corresponding above:

  ```
  USERS_GROUP_A ALL=(cooluser) NOPASSWD: COMMANDS_GROUP_A
  USERS_GROUP_B ALL=(cooluser) NOPASSWD: COMMANDS_GROUP_B
  # users of the USERS_GROUP_A may run /bin/ls, /bin/cat and /usr/bin/zip
  # as the user cooluser from any machine (ALL).
  # users of the USERS_GROUP_B may run /bin/kill,/bin/cat and /usr/bin/zip
  # as the user cooluser from any machine (ALL).
  ```

  The keyword `NOPASSWD:` is to avoid the request of the password.
  Your users can execute the commands with

  ```
  sudo -u cooluser /usr/bin/zip
  ```

  **Side effect**: other users will be not able to run that command until you will not include them in the group of the owner of the file... and if it is `root` should be not so safe...

References:

- [visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor](http://www.garron.me/en/linux/visudo-command-sudoers-file-sudo-default-editor.html)
- [sudoers-to-execute-commands-as-another-user](https://serverfault.com/questions/197340/sudoers-to-execute-commands-as-another-user)